Set correct pixel color when manipulating texture buffers sdl2 rust
I am trying to make a somewhat efficient function to render a circle. I tried drawing pixel per pixel with the midpoint algorithm, but that's too slow. So after some research i opted for creating a texture, locking it and manipulating its pixels. The problem is that i cannot seem to get the right colors. Here is what I came up:
pub fn fill_circle(&mut self, center: impl Into<Vector2>, radius: impl ToF32) {
    let center = center.into();
    let r = radius.to_f32();
    let d = r * 2.0;
    let color = self.canvas.draw_color();

    let mut texture = unsafe {
        TEXTURE_CREATOR
            .get()
            .unwrap()
            .create_texture_streaming(PixelFormatEnum::RGBA8888, d as u32, d as u32)
            .unwrap()
    };

    texture.set_blend_mode(sdl2::render::BlendMode::Blend);

    texture
        .with_lock(None, |buffer, pitch| {
            for x in 0..d as usize {
                for y in 0..d as usize {
                    let circle_v = (x as f32 - r) * (x as f32 - r)
                        + (y as f32 - r) * (y as f32 - r)
                        - r * r;

                    let i = y * pitch + x * 4;

                    if circle_v <= 0.0 {
                        buffer[i] = color.r;
                        buffer[i + 1] = color.g;
                        buffer[i + 2] = color.b;
                        buffer[i + 3] = color.a;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .expect("Failed to lock texture");

    let target_rect = FRect::new(center.x - r, center.y - r, d, d);
    self.canvas
        .copy_f(&texture, None, Some(target_rect))
        .unwrap();

    unsafe { texture.destroy() };
}

Ignore the unsafe blocks, i am just prototyping. But when setting the colors in the buffer array, the colors just aren't right. If i set the draw color to cyan as an example (r: 0, g: 255, b: 255, a: 255) the circle is white, if i set magenta, its yellow.

There is a non-zero chance your buffer represents a color dot in a reverse order: ABGR. (Little-endian on your CPU arch).

The problem was that I was not checking for endianness. Since my system uses little endian byte order, so if little -> abgr, big -> rgba.
here is the texture lock callback:
        texture
            .with_lock(None, |buffer, pitch| {
                for x in 0..d as usize {
                    for y in 0..d as usize {
                        let circle_v = (x as f32 - r) * (x as f32 - r)
                            + (y as f32 - r) * (y as f32 - r)
                            - r * r;

                        let i = y * pitch + x * 4;

                        if circle_v <= 0.0 {
                            #[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
                            {
                                buffer[i] = color.a;
                                buffer[i + 1] = color.b;
                                buffer[i + 2] = color.g;
                                buffer[i + 3] = color.r;
                            }

                            #[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
                            {
                                buffer[i] = color.r;
                                buffer[i + 1] = color.g;
                                buffer[i + 2] = color.b;
                                buffer[i + 3] = color.a;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .expect("Failed to lock texture");

thanks to @AlexanderFadeev !
